# reverse bb-codes when echo

Tags: php, bbcode

I have found a code to use bb-codes in my personal message on profiles, but when i go back to settings to change the message it echo html tags instead of the bb-codes replacement.

bb-codes :

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if(isset($_POST['bio_message'])){
//BBCode Parser function
function showBBcodes($text) {
        // BBcode array
        $find = array(
                '~\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]~s',
                '~\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]~s',
                '~\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]~s',
                '~\[quote\](.*?)\[/quote\]~s',
                '~\[url\]((?:ftp|https?)://.*?)\[/url\]~s',
                '~\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]~s'
        );
        // HTML tags to replace BBcode
        $replace = array(
                '<b>$1</b>',
                '<i>$1</i>',
                '<p style="text-decoration:underline;">$1</p>',
                '<pre>$1</'.'pre>',
                '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
                '<img src="$1" alt="" />'
        );
        // Replacing the BBcodes with corresponding HTML tags
        return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}
// How to use the above function:
$text = $_POST['bio_message'];
$htmltext = showBBcodes($text);

        }

            $id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            $bio_sql = "UPDATE users SET bio = '$htmltext' WHERE id = '$id'";
            $db->query($bio_sql);
        }else{}
```

echo bio in textarea:

```
<?php
$id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
 $SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";


 $result = $db->query($SQL);

/* associative array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print(htmlentities($row['bio'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

    $result->free();
?>
```

Comment: Well, you do exactly the same just the other way round.

Comment: tried but wont work. repleaced $find and $replace aswell as switched their order.

Comment: You have to edit the regex and replacements as well.

Comment: @AvatarLandRazer please use modern solutions for BBCode, I recommend my own library https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . Happy to answer any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

```
function showHTML($text) {
    // HTML tags to replace
    $find = array(
        '~<b>(.*?)</b>~s',
        '~<i>(.*?)</i>~s',
        '~<p style="text-decoration:underline;">(.*?)</p>~s',
        '~<pre>(.*?)</pre>~s',
        '~<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>~s',
        '~<img src="(.*?)" alt="" />~s'
    );

    // BBcode array
    $replace = array(
        '[b]$1[/b]',
        '[i]$1[/i]',
        '[u]$1[/u]',
        '[quote]$1[/quote]',
        '[url]$1[/url]',
        '[img]$1[/img]'
    );

    // Replacing the BBcodes with corresponding HTML tags
    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}
```

Input:

```
<i>fsfsdfsf</i> <a href="http://abc.de">http://abc.de</a>
```

Output:

```
[i]fsfsdfsf[/i] [url]http://abc.de[/url]
```

Comment: Well first add the function to your PHP code, then call it with showHTML($text)

Comment: cant get it to work. 
i need showBBcodes($text) to get it to echo but it gets an error or something because it cuts everything below that part when i add it

Comment: I recommend you read the php basics, especially functions and their usage. You should move your original function and mine to a seperate file e.g called funtions.php and include it via include_once('functions.php');. Then all you have to do is calling the showHTML method when you want to replace BBCode with HTML and showBBcode when you want to convert HTML to BBcode

Comment: btw you dont have to move them. But it makes your code cleaner and more readable. Replace `print(htmlentities($row['bio'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));` with `print(showHTML($row['bio'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));` this should do the trick.

Comment: cant get it to echo $row['bio'], is it something im missing or misunderstand?

it checks the session for user id and then uses it to SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=... then the id, but $row['bio'] wont echo

Comment: Please show the exact code you are trying to get to work.

Comment: i have added it as a answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i am currently using to try to echo the `$row['bio']`

```
<?php                            
     function showHTML($text) {
         // HTML tags to replace
         $find = array(
             '~<b>(.*?)</b>~s',
             '~<i>(.*?)</i>~s',
             '~<p style="text-decoration:underline;">(.*?)</p>~s',
             '~<pre>(.*?)</pre>~s',
             '~<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>~s',
             '~<img src="(.*?)" alt="" />~s'
         );

         // BBcode array
         $replace = array(
             '[b]$1[/b]',
             '[i]$1[/i]',
             '[u]$1[/u]',
             '[quote]$1[/quote]',
             '[url]$1[/url]',
             '[img]$1[/img]'
         );

         // Replacing the BBcodes with corresponding HTML tags
         return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
     }

     $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
     $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

     print(showHTML($row['bio'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
 ?>
```

Comment: Oh I see it was my bad. Replace `showHTML($row['bio'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` with `htmlentities(showHTML($row['bio']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: nope, still nothing. it saves and echo how i want it on my profile but not in the textarea after submit

Comment: For me it looks like you just execute the sql query and dont even fetch the data from the database. $row['bio'] is the result of your fetching.

Comment: i noticed you edited the question and your solution works exactly how i want it now :) thanks alot for your help

Comment: Yeah you just had to add the query/fetch part, otherwise $row['bio'] would not be set and therefore throws a notice/nothing in return. You are very welcome